# antlr: how to avoid recognizing whitespaces in a rule

Tags: antlr4

I have antlr grammar like following.

```
accepted: appendix '$' pin;

pin: alphanums (connectors alphanums)+;

appendix: LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE;

alphanums: (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | INT)+;

connectors: CONNECTOR+;

LOWERCASE: [a-z]+;
UPPERCASE: [A-Z]+;
INT: [0-9]+;
CONNECTOR: ',' | 'and' | 'or';

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

it is expected to accept patterns like "a $ 100a, 101b", but it is unfortunately also accepting patterns like "a $ 100a of sth unacceptable". here "of sth unacceptable" are recognized as part of alphanums. what I really have intended the rule "alphanums" to recognize is just letters and digits, no spaces.

If I change alphanums to a lexer rule, like

```
accepted: appendix '$' pin;

pin: ALPHANUMS (connectors ALPHANUMS)+;

appendix: LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE;

ALPHANUMS: (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | INT)+;

connectors: CONNECTOR+;

LOWERCASE: [a-z]+;
UPPERCASE: [A-Z]+;
INT: [0-9]+;
CONNECTOR: ',' | 'and' | 'or';

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

The appendix rule no longer recognizes "a", since "a" is now of lexer token "ALPHANUMS".

I don't really want to change appendix rule to take ALPHANUMS, like

```
appendix: ALPHANUMS;
```

since I only intend letters for appendix, no digits there. To use ALPHANUMS I'll have to put in validation code in listener, which is extra piece of logic that also makes the grammar harder to understand.

Is there any way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you skip spaces in the lexer, then `a a` will be treated the same as `aa` in rules like `alphanums`. There's no way around it. Either don't skip spaces and account for them in the parser (usually not a viable solution), or demote the `alphanums` down to the lexer as you already tried (this is the way to go).

How about something like this:

```
accepted   : appendix '$' pin;
pin        : alphanums (connectors alphanums)+;
appendix   : LETTERS | AND | OR; // perhaps without the AND and OR?
connectors : connector+;
connector  : COMMA | AND | OR;
alphanums  : ALPHANUMS | LETTERS | AND | OR; // perhaps without the AND and OR?

AND        : 'and';
OR         : 'or';
COMMA      : ',';
LETTERS    : [a-zA-Z]+;
ALPHANUMS  : [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
WS         : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Comment: thanks. this looks like a solution. let me try it out